# Answering the cell phone from windows 7

Tags: windows-7, bluetooth

Is there anyway to answer the cell phone (mobile phone) from `Windows 7`?

I know this can be happened with `Bluetooth`, but with `USB cable`, I don't know.

With Bluetooth the PC acts like Bluetooth hands-free.

I want that operation with cable not Bluetooth.

Comment: That would be a feature your phone would have to have, and you don't tell us anything about your phone. (Though I don't know of any phone that has that feature.)

Comment: Sony Ericsson K550